# OpenCV compilation error with gcc 4.3 or above in MAC OS X

Tags: macos, opencv

I want to use BRIEF and ORB in OpenCV and in order to use SSE4.2 (to speed up matching) in OpenCV, we need to compile OpenCV with gcc 4.3 or above and SSE4.2 option enabled.

I have no problem compiling OpenCV with gcc4.2.1 which is the default version in my Mac OS X 10.6.8.

Then, I have tried using Macports to install gcc4.3, 4.4, 4.5, 4.6, 4.7, 4.8 and switched gcc to the new one. I first tried installing OpenCV with default settings like instruction in OpenCV website. But I couldn't compile the code like when I used gcc4.2.1. Please note that, no problem with gcc4.2.1. Problems happen with gcc4.3 or above.

Could you please give me an advice where the problems come from? It seems that the errors come from compiler compatibility.

Some errors are:

```
OpenCV-2.4.0/modules/highgui/src/window_cocoa.mm: In function 'void cvDestroyAllWindows()':
OpenCV-2.4.0/modules/highgui/src/window_cocoa.mm:198:21: error: expected ';' before 'in'
OpenCV-2.4.0/modules/highgui/src/window_cocoa.mm:198:21: error: 'in' was not declared in this scope
OpenCV-2.4.0/modules/highgui/src/window_cocoa.mm:198:24: error: expected ';' before 'list'


In file included from /opt/local/include/libavformat/avformat.h:42:0,
                 from OpenCV-2.4.0/modules/highgui/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:78,
                 from OpenCV-2.4.0/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:56,
                 from OpenCV-2.4.0/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp:45:
/opt/local/include/libavcodec/avcodec.h:554:1: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
Please submit a full bug report,
```

Comment: For reference, the offending code seems to be: `for(NSString *key in list)`. I usually don't use this `in` syntax in C++ so I'm not too familiar with it, but maybe someone else can use it to answer the question.

Comment: Furthermore, `internal compiler error: Segmentation fault Please submit a full bug report` sounds scary, perhaps something went wrong with the installation of gcc or perhaps you uncovered some sort of bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `for(NSString *key in list)` in window_cocoa.mm is an Objective-C 2 construct and is compiled as Objective-C++

gcc from GNU does not support the version 2 syntax and so cannot compile this. gcc4.2 from Apple includes Apple extensions including Objective C 2 but pure gcc does not.

You'll have to try the clang compiler.

Comment: Thanks. But with gcc4.2 there is no problem with compilation? Problems happen with gcc4.3 or higher.

Comment: Xcode includes an Apple gcc4.2 which understands the Objective C version 2 syntax

Comment: But with gcc4.2, I can't enable sse4.2 (POPCNT instruction in core i7) and get speed up.

Comment: @alibaba - you need to use an Apple compiler unless gcc 4.6 changes http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/changes.html are enough

Comment: I did use Apple-gcc4.2 but it doesn't enable sse4.2 :-(

Comment: You have a choice try to use Apple's clang does SEE or if gcc 4.6+ does Objective C 2 syntax